# Jira: Filter output as JQL-parameter without add-ons

Tags: jira

Is it possible to use native JQL-functionality to search utilizing the search results of another query?

For example:

- **Query A**: *issuetype = Epic AND priority in (1,2,3)*

  - Filter ID: 12000
- **Query B**: *issuetype = Story AND "Epic link" in (filter = 12000)*

Note: Company policy restricts add-on usage, that's why I'm looking for a JQL-native solution.